# Integrating APM with WSO2 Governance Registry

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-governance-registry

I want to install API Manager in my WSO2 G-Reg.

i follow this tutorial: [Integrating APM with WSO2 Governance Registry](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Integrating+with+WSO2+Governance+Registry)

***This is my ServiceLifeCycle (WSO2 G-Reg):***

```
<!--
 ~ Copyright (c) 2005-2010, WSO2 Inc. (http://www.wso2.org) All Rights Reserved.
 ~
 ~ WSO2 Inc. licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
 ~ Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 ~ in compliance with the License.
 ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
 ~
 ~    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 ~
 ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 ~ software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 ~ "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 ~ KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 ~ specific language governing permissions and limitations
 ~ under the License.
 -->
<aspect name="ServiceLifeCycle" class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle">
    <configuration type="literal">
        <lifecycle>
            <scxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml"
                   version="1.0"
                   initialstate="Development">
                <state id="Development">
                    <datamodel>
                        <data name="checkItems">
                            <item name="Code Completed" forEvent="">
                                <!--<permissions>
                                    <permission roles=""/>
                                </permissions>
                                <validations>
                                    <validation forEvent="" class="">
                                        <parameter name="" value=""/>
                                    </validation>
                                </validations>-->
                            </item>
                            <item name="WSDL, Schema Created" forEvent="">
                            </item>
                            <item name="QoS Created" forEvent="">
                            </item>
                        </data>
                        <data name="transitionExecution">
                            <execution forEvent="Promote" class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.ServiceVersionExecutor">
                                <parameter name="currentEnvironment" value="/_system/governance/trunk/{@resourcePath}/{@version}/{@resourceName}"/>
                                <parameter name="targetEnvironment" value="/_system/governance/branches/testing/{@resourcePath}/{@version}/{@resourceName}"/>
                                <parameter name="service.mediatype" value="application/vnd.wso2-service+xml"/>
                                <parameter name="wsdl.mediatype" value="application/wsdl+xml"/>
                                <parameter name="endpoint.mediatype" value="application/vnd.wso2.endpoint"/>
                            </execution>
                        </data>
                        <data name="transitionUI">
                            <ui forEvent="Promote" href="../lifecycles/pre_invoke_aspect_ajaxprocessor.jsp?currentEnvironment=/_system/governance/trunk/"/>
                        </data>
                        <!--<data name="transitionValidation">
                            <validation forEvent="" class="">
                                <parameter name="" value=""/>
                            </validation>
                        </data>
                        <data name="transitionPermission">
                            <permission forEvent="" roles=""/>
                        </data>
                        <data name="transitionScripts">
                            <js forEvent="">
                                <console function="">
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                    </script>
                                </console>
                                <server function="">
                                    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
                                </server>
                            </js>
                        </data>
                        <data name="transitionApproval">
                            <approval forEvent="Promote" roles="" votes="2"/>
                        </data>-->
                        <data name="transitionScripts">
                            <js forEvent="Promote">
                                <console function="showServiceList">
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        showServiceList = function() { var element = document.getElementById('hidden_media_type'); var mediaType = ""; if (element) { mediaType = element.value;} if (mediaType == "application/vnd.wso2-service+xml") { location.href = unescape("../generic/list.jsp?region=region3%26item=governance_list_service_menu%26key=service%26breadcrumb=Services%26singularLabel=Service%26pluralLabel=Services"); } }
                                    </script>
                                </console>
                            </js>
                        </data>
                    </datamodel>
                    <transition event="Promote" target="Testing"/>
                </state>
                <state id="Testing">
                    <datamodel>
                        <data name="checkItems">
                            <item name="Effective Inspection Completed" forEvent="">
                            </item>
                            <item name="Test Cases Passed" forEvent="">
                            </item>
                            <item name="Smoke Test Passed" forEvent="">
                            </item>
                        </data>
                        <data name="transitionExecution">
                            <execution forEvent="Promote" class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.ServiceVersionExecutor">
                                <parameter name="currentEnvironment" value="/_system/governance/branches/testing/{@resourcePath}/{@version}/{@resourceName}"/>
                                <parameter name="targetEnvironment" value="/_system/governance/branches/production/{@resourcePath}/{@version}/{@resourceName}"/>
                                <parameter name="service.mediatype" value="application/vnd.wso2-service+xml"/>
                                <parameter name="wsdl.mediatype" value="application/wsdl+xml"/>
                                <parameter name="endpoint.mediatype" value="application/vnd.wso2.endpoint"/>
                            </execution>
                            <execution forEvent="Demote" class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.DemoteActionExecutor">
                            </execution>
                        </data>
                        <data name="transitionUI">
                            <ui forEvent="Promote" href="../lifecycles/pre_invoke_aspect_ajaxprocessor.jsp?currentEnvironment=/_system/governance/branches/testing/"/>
                        </data>
                        <data name="transitionScripts">
                            <js forEvent="Promote">
                                <console function="showServiceList">
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        showServiceList = function() { var element = document.getElementById('hidden_media_type'); var mediaType = ""; if (element) { mediaType = element.value;} if (mediaType == "application/vnd.wso2-service+xml") { location.href = unescape("../generic/list.jsp?region=region3%26item=governance_list_service_menu%26key=service%26breadcrumb=Services%26singularLabel=Service%26pluralLabel=Services"); } }
                                    </script>
                                </console>
                            </js>
                        </data>
                    </datamodel>
                    <transition event="Promote" target="Production"/>
                    <transition event="Demote" target="Development"/>
                </state>
                <state id="Production">
                    <datamodel>
                        <data name="transitionExecution">
                            <execution forEvent="Demote" class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.DemoteActionExecutor">
                            </execution>
                            <execution forEvent="Publish" class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.ServiceToAPIExecutor">
                               <parameter name="apim.endpoint" value="http://localhost:9764/"/>
                               <parameter name="apim.username" value="admin"/>
                               <parameter name="apim.password" value="admin"/>
                               <parameter name="apim.env" value="Dev"/>
                            </execution>
                        </data>
                    </datamodel>
                    <transition event="Publish" target="Published.to.APIStore"/>
                    <transition event="Demote" target="Testing"/>
                </state>
                <state id="Published.to.APIStore">
                </state>
            </scxml>
        </lifecycle>
    </configuration>
</aspect>
```

I create a new service and when i want to publish my service i have this error:

```
[2016-02-22 11:51:27,668] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.ServiceToAPIExecutor}
 -  Failed to convert service to xml content
org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.ServiceToAPIExecutor.publishDataToAPIM(Serv
iceToAPIExecutor.java:216)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.ServiceToAPIExecutor.execute(ServiceToAPIEx
ecutor.java:158)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.runCustomExecutorsCode(DefaultLifeCyc
le.java:668)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:410)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventi
ngHandler.java:338)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java
:518)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2550)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:427)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1948)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.util.InvokeAspectUtil.invokeAspect(InvokeAspectUtil.ja
va:52)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.services.LifecyclesAdminService.invokeAspect(Lifecycle
sAdminService.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:66)

        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTranspo
rtSender.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.stub.CustomLifecyclesChecklistAdminServiceStub.invokeA
spect(CustomLifecyclesChecklistAdminServiceStub.java:667)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.ui.clients.LifecycleServiceClient.invokeAspect(Lifecyc
leServiceClient.java:120)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.ui.processors.InvokeAspectProcessor.invokeAspect(Invok
eAspectProcessor.java:56)
        at org.apache.jsp.lifecycles.invoke_005faspect_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(invoke_005faspect_005fajaxproce
ssor_jsp.java:84)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java
:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:2842)
        at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:2828)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.ServiceToAPIExecutor.publishDataToAPIM(Serv
iceToAPIExecutor.java:200)
        ... 77 more
[2016-02-22 11:51:27,682] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle} -  org.wso2.ca
rbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution failed for action : Publish
[2016-02-22 11:51:27,683] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.util.InvokeAspectUtil} -  Failed
 to invoke action Publish of aspect ServiceLifeCycle on resource /_system/governance/branches/production/services/servic
ea/1.0.0/Service A. Execution failed for action : Publish
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution failed for action : Publish
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:440)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventi
ngHandler.java:338)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java
:518)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2550)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:427)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1948)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.util.InvokeAspectUtil.invokeAspect(InvokeAspectUtil.ja
va:52)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.services.LifecyclesAdminService.invokeAspect(Lifecycle
sAdminService.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:66)

        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTranspo
rtSender.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.stub.CustomLifecyclesChecklistAdminServiceStub.invokeA
spect(CustomLifecyclesChecklistAdminServiceStub.java:667)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.ui.clients.LifecycleServiceClient.invokeAspect(Lifecyc
leServiceClient.java:120)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.custom.lifecycles.checklist.ui.processors.InvokeAspectProcessor.invokeAspect(Invok
eAspectProcessor.java:56)
        at org.apache.jsp.lifecycles.invoke_005faspect_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(invoke_005faspect_005fajaxproce
ssor_jsp.java:84)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java
:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

***My WSO2 G-Reg*** --> https://localhost:9443/carbon

***My WSO2 APM*** --> https://localhost:<9443+offset>/carbon

***offset = 1***

Comment: Could be some config issue, since you get a null pointer. Can you double check the configs

Comment: @harsha89 i have check the configs and i have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

According to the error stack trace, Service artifact you are going to publish as API doesn't contain service endpoints. Service Endpoint is a must attribute to create an API definition at the APIStore.

Please check whether you have mentioned endpoint details in Service metadata. 
[image]

It will be great if you can include the G-Reg + APIM versions you are using.